# Manga with boy in a magic school

Tags: story-identification, manga

I know the plot it's like when the boy was young, he was running from a gang, and they were with this red-haired girl, and he got away. But years later, he joined a magic school where that same girl was looked up to and one of the best students in magic, and she also recognized him as did he.

I don't know much after this except that he is in the level 5 group but wanted to go higher in rank. The students got mad and wanted a fair trial or something, so there was a test where it is about teleporting to the other side of the cliff, but the MC was late to it because he fell asleep practicing.

Answer (score 2):

This is [The Infinite Mage](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ev4ygbg/the-infinite-mage).

[image]

> Abandoned at birth in a stable, Shirone was raised by commoners. As a child, he had gifted insight and had learned how to read. After visiting the city, he finally saw the workings of magic, which he was immensely curious about. This inspired Shirone's dream of becoming a mage. However, the city was a place with a cruel and rigid social hierarchy. Here, Shirone discovered the hidden side of the world before he even reached adulthood... Will Shirone be able to achieve his dream of becoming a mage in this twisted world?

The redhead girl is called Amy Karmis.

[image]

Comment: i love you so much